# Partial ordering of function templates - ambiguous call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, ambiguous

Consider this piece of C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> void f(T, const char*) //#1
{ 
    std::cout << "f(T, const char*)\n"; 
}

template<std::size_t N> void f(int, const char(&)[N]) //#2
{ 
    std::cout << "f(int, const char (&)[N])\n"; 
}

int main()
{
    f(7, "ab");
}
```

Alright, so... which overload is chosen? Before spilling the beans with compiler output, let's try to reason about this.

(All references to sections are for the final standard document for C++11, ISO/IEC 14882:2011.)

`T` from *#1* is deduced to `int`, `N` from *#2* is deduced to `3`, both specializations are candidates, both are viable, so far so good. Which one is best?

First, the implicit conversions needed to match function arguments with function parameters are considered. For the first argument, no conversion is needed in either case (*identity conversion*), `int` everywhere, so the two functions are equally good. For the second one, the argument type is `const char[3]`, and the two conversions are:

- for *#1*, *array-to-pointer conversion*, category *lvalue transformation*, according to `[13.3.3.1.1]`; this conversion category is ignored when comparing conversion sequences according to `[13.3.3.2]`, so this is basically the same as *identity conversion* for this purpose;
- for *#2*, the parameter is of reference type and binds directly to the argument, so, according to `[13.3.3.1.4]`, this is again *identity conversion*.

Again, no luck: the two functions are still equally good. Both being template specializations, we now have to see which function template, if any, is *more specialized* (`[14.5.6.2]` and `[14.8.2.4]`).

EDIT 3: The description below is close, but not quite accurate. See my answer for what I believe to be the correct description of the process.

- Template argument deduction with *#1* as parameter and *#2* as argument: we invent a value `M` to substitute for `N`, `T` deduced as `int`, `const char*` as parameter can be initialized from an argument of type `char[M]`, everything's fine. As far as I can tell, *#2* is at least as specialized as *#1* for all types involved.
- Template argument deduction with *#2* as parameter and *#1* as argument: we invent a type `U` to substitute for `T`, a parameter of type `int` cannot be initialized from an argument of type `U` (unrelated types), a parameter of type `char[N]` cannot be initialized from an argument of type `const char*`, and the value of the non-type parameter `N` cannot be deduced from the arguments, so... everything fails. As far as I can tell, *#1* is not at least as specialized as *#2* for all types involved.

EDIT 1: The above has been edited based on comments from Columbo and dyp, to reflect the fact that references are removed before attempting template argument deduction in this case.

EDIT 2: Based on info from hvd, top level *cv-qualifiers* are also removed. In this case, it means `const char[N]` becomes `char[N]`, because *cv-qualifiers* on array elements apply to the array itself as well (an `array of const` is also a `const array`, so to speak); this wasn't obvious at all in the C++11 standard, but has been clarified for C++14.

Based on the above, I'd say partial ordering of function templates should choose *#2* as more specialized, and the call should resolve to it with no ambiguity.

Now, back to the harsh reality. Both GCC 4.9.1 and Clang 3.5.0, with the following options

```
-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic
```

reject the call as ambiguous, with similar error messages. The error from Clang is:

```
prog.cc:16:2: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(7, "ab");
    ^
prog.cc:4:27: note: candidate function [with T = int] 
template<typename T> void f(T, const char*) //#1 
                         ^
prog.cc:9:30: note: candidate function [with N = 3] 
template<std::size_t N> void f(int, const char(&)[N]) //#2 
                            ^
```

Visual C++ 2013's IntelliSense (based on the EDG compiler, as far as I know) also flags the call as ambiguous. Funnily enough, the VC++ compiler goes ahead and compiles the code with no errors, choosing *#2*. (Yay! It agrees with me, so it must be right.)

The obvious question for the experts is, **why is the call ambiguous?** What am I missing (in the partial ordering area, I would guess)?

Comment: Neither I, this is a well detailed question that shows effort. Cannot help with your issue, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB No, I don't think so. As explained in the question, the fact that `const char*` and `const char[3]` are equally valid when binding to a `const char[3]` argument is no surprise. That's why we have to get to partial ordering of function templates to decide which overload to call.

Comment: I would actually prefer such calls to be flagged as ambiguous since it's too easy to make a mistake by calling a wrong function. Perhaps VC++ agrees more with the spirit of the standard than the letter of the standard.

Comment: I think the issue is unrelated to the first parameter: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a35812f811b4a930 -- it is possible the result is due to the removal of the reference type in partial ordering.

Comment: @dyp The main reason for having `T` in *#1* was to make the first overload also a template (otherwise, a plain function would have been preferred over a template specialization). If anything, the first parameter would be one more reason to consider *#2* as more specialized (`int` vs. `T`), so it has some sort of relevance, I think.

Comment: What my example shows is that neither is *more* specialized based on the `char const(&)[N]` vs `char const*` function parameter (at least, that's what clang++ thinks). With the `int` vs `T` function parameter, we should be able to conclude that neither is *as specialized* based on the array/pointer parameter - otherwise, the first function parameter would settle it.

Comment: Even with the reference removed, `N` cannot be deduced from the argument `const char*`, so template deduction should still fail, while binding arguments the other way around works, so I would expect *#2* to be more specialized with regards to this argument. I can't figure out what's wrong with this reasoning. Based on this, Clang's output would be wrong in your test case as well.

Comment: Anyway, I will edit the question to remove the reference, to keep it as correct as possible until we figure out what's going on.

Comment: From the C++03 Standard, and some subordinate clause in a C++1y draft: it might be possible that the types must be an exact match w/o implicit conversions to count as *at least as specialized*.

Comment: @dyp Good point, I'll try to investigate this further.

Comment: Working from the comments on my now deleted answer: [here's another example, without the first argument and without `const`, where you might expect the array overload to be called](http://ideone.com/Acw788), but compilers flag it as ambiguous anyway.

Comment: Alright, I think we're getting somewhere. Based on hvd's last comment on his deleted answer: `[14.8.2.4]` says that, after the preliminary transformations, type deduction is done as described in `[14.8.2.5]`, which is **not** how types are deduced from function calls, but rather *deducing template arguments from a type*. The rules in there don't allow for the same conversions as for function parameters; I guess they could be thought of as the same rules used for deducing class template parameters from the corresponding arguments.

Comment: A bit counter-intuitive, maybe, but I guess the reason behind stricter matching is precisely to flag as ambiguous calls that would otherwise go through and possibly call the unexpected overload. In this case, however, they end up not calling the expected overload. Well, you can't have it all, I guess...

Comment: @EvanCarslake sometimes sadly downvotes are not about the content, especially with questions since you don't have to use rep to downvote a question.

Comment: @hvd So, who's writing the answer? I think it's worth explaining how things actually work. I could write it myself, but choosing my own answer somehow doesn't seem as much fun.

Comment: @dyp Both you and hvd more or less found the answer, so, if any of you wants to write a complete answer, please go ahead.

Comment: @bogdan I'm actually quite surprised by some of the details that have come up and I'm currently not confident enough in my own understanding of the matter to post an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm posting the details of my current understanding of the issue as an answer. I'm not sure it will be the final word on this, but it could serve as a basis for further discussion if needed. The comments from dyp, hvd and Columbo have been essential for finding the various bits of information referenced below.

As I suspected, the problem is with the rules for partial ordering of function templates. Section `[14.8.2.4]` (*Deducing template arguments during partial ordering*) says that, after the preliminary transformations that remove references and cv-qualifiers, type deduction is done as described in `[14.8.2.5]` (*Deducing template arguments from a type*). That section is different from the one that refers to function calls - that would be `[14.8.2.1]` (*Deducing template arguments from a function call*).

When template parameters are deduced from function argument types, there are a few special cases that are allowed; for example, a template parameter `T` used in a function parameter of type `T*` can be deduced when the function argument is `T[i]`, because the array-to-pointer conversion is allowed in this case. However, **this is not the deduction process that's used during partial ordering**, even though we're still talking about functions.

I guess the easy way to think about the rules for template argument deduction during partial ordering is to say they're the same rules as for deducing template arguments when matching **class template** specializations.

Clear as mud? Perhaps a couple of examples will help.

This works, because it uses the rules for *deducing template arguments from a function call*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void f(T*)
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<T, int>::value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[3];
    f(a);
}
```

and prints `1`.

This doesn't, because it uses the rules for *deducing template arguments from a type*:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct A;

template<typename T> struct A<T*>
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "specialization\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A<int[3]>::f();
}
```

and the error from Clang is

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'A<int [3]>'
```

The specialization cannot be used, because `T*` and `int[3]` don't match in this case, so the compiler tries to instantiate the primary template.

**It's this second kind of deduction that's used during partial ordering.**

---

Let's get back to our function template declarations:

```
template<typename T> void f(T, const char*); //#1
template<std::size_t N> void f(int, const char(&)[N]); //#2
```

My description of the process for partial ordering becomes:

- Template argument deduction with *#1* as parameter and *#2* as argument: we invent a value `M` to substitute for `N`, `T` is deduced as `int`, but a parameter of type `const char*` **does not** match an argument of type `char[M]`, so *#2* is **not** at least as specialized as *#1* for the second pair of types.
- Template argument deduction with *#2* as parameter and *#1* as argument: we invent a type `U` to substitute for `T`, `int` and `U` do not match (different types), a parameter of type `char[N]` does not match an argument of type `const char*`, and the value of the non-type template parameter `N` cannot be deduced from the arguments, so *#1* is **not** at least as specialized as *#2* for either pair of types.

Since, in order to be chosen, a template needs to be at least as specialized as the other for all types, it follows that *neither template is more specialized than the other* and the call is ambiguous.

---

The explanation above goes somewhat against the description of a similar problem in [Core Language Active Issue 1610](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1610) (link provided by hvd).

The example in there is:

```
template<class C> void foo(const C* val) {}
template<int N> void foo(const char (&t)[N]) {}
```

The author argues that, intuitively, the second template should be chosen as more specialized, and that this doesn't currently happen (neither template is more specialized than the other).

He then explains that the reason is the removal of the `const` qualifier from `const char[N]`, yielding `char[N]`, which causes deduction to fail with `const C*` as parameter.

However, based on my current understanding, deduction would fail in this case, `const` or no `const`. This is confirmed by the current implementations in Clang and GCC: if we remove the `const` qualifier from the parameters of both function templates and call `foo()` with a `char[3]` argument, the call is still ambiguous. Arrays and pointers simply don't match according to the current rules during partial ordering.

Having said that, I'm not a member of the committee, so there may be more to this than I currently understand.

---

Update: I've recently stumbled upon another Core active issue that goes back to 2003: [issue 402](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#402).

The example in there is equivalent to the one in [1610](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1610). The comments on the issue make it clear that the two overloads are unordered according to the partial ordering algorithm as it stands, precisely because of the lack of array-to-pointer decay rules during partial ordering.

The last comment is:

> There was some sentiment that it would be desirable to have this case
>   ordered, but we don't think it's worth spending the time to work on it
>   now. If we look at some larger partial ordering changes at some point,
>   we will consider this again.

Thus, I'm pretty confident that the interpretation I gave above is correct.

Comment: Interestingly, if you change `foo`'s parameter to `const C* const &` then it works fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad What I **don't** understand, however, is why the same solution doesn't work for the example in my question. I'd say it should be the same thing, but in that case the call is still ambiguous. Any ideas?

Comment: I was actually busy writing an answer myself until I tested out the solution for the first one and realized (just as you did) that it doesn't work. I'm just as stumped haha.

Comment: @Mehrdad I take it all back. Array-to-pointer conversions work with template argument deduction only for non-reference parameters. Adding a reference to pointer to the first overload makes it **not viable** for this call, so only the second one remains. This can be verified by changing the parameter to const C*& - it still works, while commenting out the second overload results in a compilation error - 'no matching function', both with or without `const`.

Comment: In my example, there's no template argument deduction involved for the second parameter of *#1*, and that's what makes the difference: for `const char*&`, the overload is not viable (which resolves the ambiguity, yay!); for `const char* const&`, I think a temporary gets created, and the `const&` binds to it. Why this conversion isn't worse than direct reference binding for the second parameter of *#2*, I'm not sure.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. `[13.3.3.1.4] paragraph 2`: When a parameter of reference type is not bound directly to an argument expression, the conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument expression to the underlying type of the reference. In this case, that conversion sequence is array-to-pointer, which is indistinguishable from identity.

Comment: @Mehrdad Hey, your comment triggered an investigation that's worth an answer of its own...

Comment: Haha, do you mean I should post it as an answer?

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm not sure how this fits within SO rules. Strictly speaking, this discussion doesn't provide an answer to the original question, and the additional code from the core language issue was just included in my answer as a kind of warning that there may still be inaccuracies in my explanation. I would see this as a separate question - answer pair, the question being 'how to resolve the ambiguity', addressing both cases (`const C*` and `const char*`), all combinations of `const` qualifications and explaining what happens in each case.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I don't see myself doing that anytime soon. If you feel like working on this, I think that would be great. There are also at least a couple other questions with similar code samples, I'm not sure if it would be better to add answers to those instead.

Comment: Hmm not sure if I'll get a chance to take a better look at it unfortunately, but if I get anywhere I'll let you know.

Comment: @Mehrdad I've seen the `* const&` vs array distinction before; there's probably already an answer or a comment on SO that mentions it. For example, I've mentioned it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23295859), but not as a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I thought the problem with you code is that you were not accounting for function type adjustment. Function type adjustment causes an array with bounds to be interpreted as a pointer to the type.
I tried to find the solution to your problem by asking the compiler what it is seeing statically via templates, but instead I get more interesting results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void is_same( const T* _left, const char(&_right)[N] )
{
 typedef decltype(_left) LeftT;
 typedef decltype(_right) RightT;

 std::cout << std::is_same<LeftT,const char*>::value << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::is_same<LeftT,const char(&)[3]>::value << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::is_same<LeftT,const char(&)[4]>::value << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::is_same<RightT,const char*>::value << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::is_same<RightT,const char(&)[3]>::value << std::endl;
 std::cout << std::is_same<RightT,const char(&)[4]>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
 std::cout << std::boolalpha;

 is_same( "ab", "cd" );

 return 0;
}
```

The output yields:
true
false
false
false
true
false

The compiler is capable of distinguishing the arguments in this case.

Edit 1:
Here's some more code. Introducing rvalue references makes functions more distinguishable.

```
#include <iostream>

// f
template<typename _T>
 void f( _T, const char* )
 {
  std::cout << "f( _T, const char* )" << std::endl;
 }

template<std::size_t _kN>
 void f( int, const char(&)[_kN] )
 {
  std::cout << "f( int, const char (&)[_kN] )" << std::endl;
 }

// g
template<typename _T>
 void g( _T, const char* )
 {
  std::cout << "g( _T, const char* )" << std::endl;
 }

template<std::size_t _kN>
 void g( int, const char(&&)[_kN] )
 {
  std::cout << "g( int, const char (&&)[_kN] )" << std::endl;
 }

// h
template<std::size_t _kN>
 void h( int, const char(&)[_kN] )
 {
  std::cout << "h( int, const char(&)[_kN] )" << std::endl;
 }

template<std::size_t _kN>
 void h( int, const char(&&)[_kN] )
 {
  std::cout << "h( int, const char (&&)[_kN] )" << std::endl;
 }

int main()
{
 //f( 7, "ab" ); // Error!
 //f( 7, std::move("ab") ); // Error!
 f( 7, static_cast<const char*>("ab") ); // OK
 //f( 7, static_cast<const char(&)[3]>("ab") ); // Error!
 //f( 7, static_cast<const char(&&)[3]>("ab") ); // Error!

 g( 7, "ab" ); // OK
 //g( 7, std::move("ab") ); // Error!
 g( 7, static_cast<const char*>("ab") ); // OK
 g( 7, static_cast<const char(&)[3]>("ab") ); // OK
 //g( 7, static_cast<const char (&&)[3]>("ab") ); // Error!

 h( 7, "ab" ); // OK (What? Why is this an lvalue?)
 h( 7, std::move("ab") ); // OK
 //h( 7, static_cast<const char*>("ab") ); // Error
 h( 7, static_cast<const char(&)[3]>("ab") ); // OK
 h( 7, static_cast<const char(&&)[3]>("ab") ); // OK

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array-to-pointer conversion has been discussed both here, in the question, answer, and comments, and elsewhere on SO. `_right` is declared as a reference, that's why it's not adjusted in any way. If it were declared as `const char _right[N]`, *then* it would be equivalent to `const char* _right` (C legacy), and `N` could not be deduced. The way the function template is declared, the second, third and fourth `is_same<>` tests can never yield true.

Comment: Regarding Edit 1: I wouldn't say the functions are 'more distinguishable'. `g()` falls back to the `const char*` version when passed a `const char[N]`, which is not really what we want or expect. `h()` only serves to show that string literals are lvalues (an integer literal like `7` is a prvalue, but not string literals, which are arrays of static storage duration; see [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) for details).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, having all these examples in one place as a reference for what happens in each case is useful. I'm only arguing about their meaning and general usefulness for solving the ambiguity. Note that the solution discussed in the comments above *does* solve the ambiguity in the expected way.